# Notification not triggered when app is closed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am trying to set an Alarm manager so that it runs every 15 minutes, checks if anything has been added to the database and then shows a notification. However, whilst I'm just testing this, I am trying to show the notification after 60 seconds.

The below code works perfectly when the app is open or minimised but is never called when the app is closed.

**Main Activity (onCreate())**

```
Intent alarm = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if (!alarmRunning) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

**Alarm Receiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
    context.startService(background);
}
```

}

**Background Service**

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

private Boolean isRunning;
private Context context;
private Thread backgroundThread;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.context = this;
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
}

private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "THE BACKGROUND SERVICE IS RUNNING");
        //Run actions
        showNotification(context);
        //
        stopSelf();
    }
};

private void showNotification(Context context) {
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("Notification!") // title for notification
            .setContentText("Alarm Received")
            .setSound(soundUri)// message for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.isRunning = false;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (!this.isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = true;
        this.backgroundThread.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <service android:name=".notification.BackgroundService" />

    <receiver android:name=".notification.AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I have read several posts but cannot seem to find the answer on how to resolve this so that the notification can still be shown/checked for when the app is closed and by closed I mean where the user removes the app from the running apps list.

Comment: just recomendation, use `IntentService` instead of receiver+service, that much simplier. It's working in background thread and stops itself after task finish

Comment: is your device in sleep mode or screen is off when you try it? on which device and os version you have tested it?

Comment: extend from `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead of `BroadcastReceiver` and use `IntentService`

Comment: What device ar4e you testing on? Have you tried also on other devices or on the emulator?

Comment: @DavidWasser Currently Testing on the GenyMotion Simulator with a Nexus 5 & 5X but have also tried on a BlackBerry PRIV device too where the service doesn't seem to work when the app is closed but works fine if the device has just been booted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to resolve this by using onTaskRemoved() to restart the service.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()");

    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

Comment: where do we have to put this function in, is it in the activity that is the notification reciever/broadcast reciever?

Answer (score 1):

**Try change alarm code:**

```
        final int ALARM_ID = 1234; // your alarm id
        startAlarm(600); // trigger after 10 minutes

        public void startAlarm(int seconds) { // set alarm in seconds
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (seconds * 1000), pendingIntent);
        }

        public void cancelAlarm() { // to cancel alarm before trigger   
            Log.d("lucas", "cancelAlarm");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            pendingIntent.cancel();
        } 

        public boolean hasAlarm() { // check alarm is running
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            return (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        }
```

**Not call** `stopSelf()` method, he may kill application. It is the running service in the background that keeps the application process alive. Without service running, the system may kill your app, remove the notification and cancel your alarms running.

**Tip:** Calling the method `stopSelf()` when the notification is clicked or canceled.

Comment: Using this in Main Activity onCreate() and also using this to replace stopSelf() in the thread of BackgroundService, still produces the same result. As soon as the application is closed (removed from the running apps list) then the notification gets removed from the status bar and the service is not fired again.